# how to force iPad to load in landscaperight orientation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have an iPad app that supports UIDeviceOrientationPortrait and UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft.

I did include this method :

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:        
      (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
        interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft );
    }
```

The issue I have is that I need it to load in the UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft mode, just for the load, because my UI controls will be setup properly. how can I force it only once on load.

One thing I wanna note is that this has to be min iOS 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had similar problem, but I wanted to change from Landscape to Portrait by force, I knew in old versions there were built in methods but unfortunately we are never sure when and what is working for us, but I gave this code a try and It worked for me, but my scenario was to forcing from landscape to portrait, which is opposite to your scenario, but anyways it works, here is the code possibly for your scenario;

```
    -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations

{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    UIApplication* application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    if (application.statusBarOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
        UIViewController *c = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
        [self presentModalViewController:c animated:NO];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }


    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

**EDIT** working on IOS 6.1 I have added two more methods which I did not add in my previous post, I add now all what is working for my application...

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{

    return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

the idea is to check the statusbar orietnation and add and dismiss a modalViewController and it works for me to force from one to another orientation.

Comment: but where in this code will it actually rotate the statusbar from landscape to portrait? or vice Versa ( depending on your scenario

Comment: I tried this solution (but a variant where they chnaged the orientation of the status bar), It did not work for me, as you can read herre ein SO. It does not work alsways. There does not exist any reliable solution. bye the way, Did you forget to change the orientation of the statusBar?

Comment: check my EDIT in answer, I have this working code in my app, If you have shouldautoRotate set to NO and preferredInterfaceOrientation is landscapeleft, then while displaying the new viewcontroller ,just add a modalViewController and dismiss it within viewWillAppear, this does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Even if this answer is not what you expected:

Give yourself a favor: it is really complex to force the device into a specific orientation.

You can search here on SO, what all works and does not work, and works in 6.1 and not in 6.01. and so on.

So fastest and safest is, to fix your code such that it can corectly initialize in both orientations.

Answer (score 0):

Update in the Project Settings OR the info file.
In iOS 6.x you should override `supportedInterfaceOrientations`.
Try also `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation`.

Comment: but I want the porject to support two orientations after the load, just force it to load in landscape just for the load.

Comment: I added another method to override -  preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation. Did you try to see if this force landscape?

Answer (score 0):

Despite any app `Info.plist` settings or `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` (or `-shouldAutorotate`) method overrides, view controllers start off in portrait and are then rotated into landscape by iOS.

What is preventing your UI layout from being setup properly?